# How to save HAR files from a Windows application integrated with Chromium app?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, har

We have a Windows application that is integrated with Helix Server (Chromium app).  We use LeanFT for automating the Windows application.  We also need the performance logs (HAR file) for the scenarios we test.  By pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> we can manually open the Devtools and check the logs, but when automating we need to save the HAR files.  I have tried HttpWatch and BrowserMobProxy that saves HAR files from browser using the driver but am not able to save them from a standalone Windows application.  Please let me know if anyone has tried saving HAR files from a client application.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to set your Application Under Test to use a proxy, then you should be able to use Browsermob.

It would be something along the lines of;

1. Start Browsermob
2. Request creation of proxy server via Browsermob API on a known port, say 9091
3. Use Browsermob API to start HAR file capture
4. Start your Application Under Test, configured to proxy via port 9091
5. Perform Test
6. Use Browsermob API to download HAR file
7. Use Browsermob API to stop proxy on port 9091